# ImageResizer license not working under Cloudfront CDN

Tags: imageresizer

I own a performance license for ImageResizing for the domain ***.com
The domain is pointing to Cloudfront CDN which then points to a load balancer which has servers under it. Because of this, the requests getting to our server is from the domain ***.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com which makes the license invalid. Do anyone know how we can overcome this issue?

I own a performance license for ImageResizing for the domain ***.com
The domain is pointing to Cloudfront CDN which then points to a load balancer which has servers under it. Because of this, the requests getting to our server is from the domain ***.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com which makes the license invalid. Do anyone know how we can overcome this issue?

```
Image resizer diagnostic sheet      ***.com 10/29/2015 9:43:26 AM

2 Issues detected:

resizer configuration(Error):   No license found for domain ***.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com - features installed: R4Performance or R4BlobProviders


(Warning):  NoCache is only for development usage, and cannot scale to production use.
            Add DiskCache or CloudFront for production use

Assembly use report: 


You are using plugins and assemblies from the V4 Performance Edition.


----------------

License keys

List of installed domain licenses:
***.com => R4Performance

----------------



Registered plugins:

ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.DefaultEncoder
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.NoCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.ClientCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.Diagnostic
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.WebConfigLicenseReader
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.SizeLimiting
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.MvcRoutingShimPlugin
ImageResizer.Plugins.S3Reader2.S3Reader2
ImageResizer.Plugins.LicenseVerifier.LicenseEnforcer`1[ImageResizer.Storage.BlobProviderBase]
ImageResizer.Plugins.AnimatedGifs.AnimatedGifs
ImageResizer.Plugins.PrettyGifs.PrettyGifs
ImageResizer.Plugins.RemoteReader.RemoteReaderPlugin

Configuration:

<resizer>
<pipeline fakeExtensions=".ashx" />
<remotereader signingKey="" allowAllSignedRequests="true" allowRedirects="5">
<allow domain="*" />
</remotereader>
<plugins>
<add name="S3Reader2" vpp="true" buckets="***-uploads" prefix="~/s3/" checkForModifiedFiles="false" useSsl="false" accessKeyId="" secretAccessKey="" useSubdomains="false" region="us-west-1" />
<add name="AnimatedGifs" />
<add name="PrettyGifs" />
</plugins>
<clientcache minutes="1440" />
<licenses>
<license>

       ***.com(R4Performance includes R4Performance)
:***
      </license>
</licenses>
</resizer>


Accepted querystring keys:

quality, format, thumbnail, colors, dither, maxwidth, maxheight, width, height, w, h, crop, page, bgcolor, rotate, flip, sourceFlip, sFlip, sRotate, borderWidth, borderColor, paddingWidth, paddingColor, frame, useresizingpipeline, cache, process, margin, dpi, zoom, autorotate, 

Accepted file extensions:

bmp, gif, exif, png, tif, tiff, tff, jpg, jpeg, jpe, jif, jfif, jfi, 

Environment information:

Running Microsoft-IIS/8.5 on Microsoft Windows NT 6.3.9600.0 and CLR 4.0.30319.42000
Trust level: Unrestricted
OS bitness: AMD64
Executing assembly: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
IntegratedPipeline: True

Installed HttpModules: 

System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyOutputCache)
System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keySession)
System.Web.Security.WindowsAuthenticationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyWindowsAuthentication)
System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyFormsAuthentication)
System.Web.Security.DefaultAuthenticationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyDefaultAuthentication)
System.Web.Security.RoleManagerModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyRoleManager)
System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyUrlAuthorization)
System.Web.Security.FileAuthorizationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyFileAuthorization)
System.Web.Security.AnonymousIdentificationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyAnonymousIdentification)
System.Web.Profile.ProfileModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyProfile)
System.Web.UrlMappingsModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyUrlMappingsModule)
System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyUrlRoutingModule-4.0)
System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35          (under keyScriptModule-4.0)
ImageResizer.InterceptModule, ImageResizer, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null          (under keyImageResizingModule)

Loaded assemblies:

mscorlib                                 Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.81.0        Info: 4.6.81.0
System.Web                               Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.81.0        Info: 4.6.81.0
System                                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.81.0        Info: 4.6.81.0
System.Core                              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.81.0        Info: 4.6.81.0
System.Configuration                     Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.81.0        Info: 4.6.81.0
System.Xml                               Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.81.0        Info: 4.6.81.0
System.Web.ApplicationServices           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.81.0        Info: 4.6.81.0
System.Runtime.Caching                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.81.0        Info: 4.6.81.0
Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.33440 Info: 4.0.30319.33440
Microsoft.JScript                        Assembly: 10.0.0.0        File: 14.0.81.0       Info: 14.0.81.0
App_global.asax.9b8m6vn6                 Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
***.Shared                          Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.0.0        
ImageResizer.Plugins.RemoteReader        Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.4.934       Info: 4.0.4  Commit: 9f75f3637f9b00eb64acf004adaa066b47585638
System.Web.Extensions                    Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.81.0        Info: 4.6.81.0
Microsoft.CSharp                         Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.33440 Info: 4.0.30319.33440
System.Data                              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.81.0        Info: 4.6.81.0
System.Web.Services                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.81.0        Info: 4.6.81.0
System.Drawing                           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.93.0        Info: 4.6.93.0
System.EnterpriseServices                Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.33440 Info: 4.0.30319.33440
System.IdentityModel                     Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.81.0        Info: 4.6.81.0
System.Runtime.Serialization             Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.81.0        Info: 4.6.81.0
System.ServiceModel                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.81.0        Info: 4.6.81.0
System.ServiceModel.Activation           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.81.0        Info: 4.6.81.0
System.ServiceModel.Web                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.81.0        Info: 4.6.81.0
System.Activities                        Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.81.0        Info: 4.6.81.0
System.ServiceModel.Activities           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.81.0        Info: 4.6.81.0
System.WorkflowServices                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.33440 Info: 4.0.30319.33440
System.Data.DataSetExtensions            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.33440 Info: 4.0.30319.33440
System.Xml.Linq                          Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.33440 Info: 4.0.30319.33440
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations    Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.81.0        Info: 4.6.81.0
System.Web.DynamicData                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.33440 Info: 4.0.30319.33440
AWSSDK.Core                              Assembly: 3.1.0.0         File: 3.1.3.2        
AWSSDK.S3                                Assembly: 3.1.0.0         File: 3.1.3.3        
***.Configuration                   Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.0.0        
***.Extensions                      Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.0.0        
ImageResizer                             Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.4.934       Info: 4.0.4  Commit: 9f75f3637f9b00eb64acf004adaa066b47585638
ImageResizer.Plugins.AnimatedGifs        Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.4.934       Info: 4.0.4  Commit: 9f75f3637f9b00eb64acf004adaa066b47585638
ImageResizer.Plugins.PrettyGifs          Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.4.934       Info: 4.0.4  Commit: 9f75f3637f9b00eb64acf004adaa066b47585638
ImageResizer.Plugins.S3Reader2           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.4.934       Info: 4.0.4  Commit: 9f75f3637f9b00eb64acf004adaa066b47585638
ImageResizer.Storage                     Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.4.934       Info: 4.0.4  Commit: 9f75f3637f9b00eb64acf004adaa066b47585638
log4net                                  Assembly: 1.2.13.0        File: 1.2.13.0        Info: 1.2
Newtonsoft.Json                          Assembly: 7.0.0.0         File: 7.0.1.18622    
ServiceStack.Interfaces                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.46.0       
ServiceStack.Text                        Assembly: 4.0.46.0        File: 4.0.46.0       
System.Numerics                          Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.81.0        Info: 4.6.81.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a custom name? I.e, `myinstance.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com`? If so, this would be the domain you would register the license key under. ImageResizer can't know what domain name it's published under unless that name is transmitted to it via HTTP as part of the HOST header. (Or, another header, if the original domain is forwarded somehow - we could add a fallback path - if so, open an issue (or PR) on Github).

You might consider a DRM-free license (Like [Elite](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/editions/elite)) to reduce the long-term hassle associated with changing load balancers and configurations. We don't suggest domain-restricted licenses for complex setups, *particularly* at a scale that requires load balancing.

Also, keep in mind that it is 100% open-source (half AGPL 3, half Apache 2), and you're legally free to strip the DRM out and make your own builds, even under the commercial license terms. We really don't mind.

Comment: hi Nathanael. Thank you for your answer. If we remove the DRM are we 100% ok? Anyway we bought a license for our domain so the only issue is that we are under a load balancer but the only domain that we are using this license on is the domain for which we bought the license.

Comment: Yes, you are free to remove the DRM and recompile. See [our Domain license terms](http://imageresizing.net/licenses/domain). You can't redistribute the DRM-free version to other users unless they have a license as well, however.